# linear layout click not working, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

i have a view that i want to set it clickable to open a new activity. the code runs without any errors but when i click on a list in the main activity, nothing happens. the list displays alright but when a particular data is clicked, nothing at all happens. this is the code for the adapter

```
package com.example.helpresponse;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

public class TargetDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TargetDataAdapter.TargetViewHolder>{

    ArrayList<AndroidTargets> targetsArrayList;
    private Context context;
    private HandleClick mHandleClick;


    public TargetDataAdapter(ArrayList<AndroidTargets> mTargetData) {
        targetsArrayList = mTargetData;
    }

    public void setmHandleClick(HandleClick handleClick) {
        this.mHandleClick = handleClick;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TargetViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        context = viewGroup.getContext();
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.target_row,viewGroup,false);
        return new TargetViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TargetViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.androidTargetName.setText(targetsArrayList.get(i).FIELD1 );
        viewHolder.androidTargetNumber.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "API Level: %d", targetsArrayList.get(i).FIELD2));
        viewHolder.androidTargetShortName.setText(targetsArrayList.get(i).FIELD3);
        viewHolder.myClickableView.setClickable(true);


/*
        viewHolder.myClickableView.setOnClickListener((v) -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class);
            //int myData = 1;
            //intent.putExtra("myDataKey", myData);
            //more intent.putExtra(s) as needed
            context.startActivity(intent);
        });

*/


        viewHolder.myClickableView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Do your stuff

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class);
                int myData = 1;
                intent.putExtra("myDataKey", myData);
                //more intent.putExtra(s) as needed
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(targetsArrayList == null)
            return 0;
        return targetsArrayList.size();
    }

    public class TargetViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected TextView androidTargetName;
        protected TextView androidTargetNumber;
        protected TextView androidTargetShortName;
        protected LinearLayout myClickableView;


        public TargetViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            myClickableView =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
            androidTargetShortName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            androidTargetName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            androidTargetNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        }
    }

    public interface HandleClick {

        void onItemClick(int index);

    }


}
```

this code is the main activity

```
package com.example.helpresponse;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ShowStudentDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    List<StudentDetails> list = new ArrayList<>();

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_student_details);



        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ShowStudentDetailsActivity.this));

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ShowStudentDetailsActivity.this);

        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Data from Firebase Database");

        progressDialog.show();

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Police").child("Chats");

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                    StudentDetails studentDetails = dataSnapshot.getValue(StudentDetails.class);

                    list.add(studentDetails);
                }

                adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(ShowStudentDetailsActivity.this, list);


                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                progressDialog.dismiss();

            }
        });


    }
}
```

this code is the layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="textview"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:clickable="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="textview"
            android:clickable="true"/>



        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="textview"
            android:clickable="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

please help, thank you

Comment: please put `log` inside `onClick` method to check if `onClick` worked or not

Comment: @Mouaad Abdelghafour AITALI: it's not working please

Answer (score 0):

You are not using your implementation, this should solve your problem.

```
public class ShowStudentDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     DatabaseReference databaseReference;
     ProgressDialog progressDialog;
     List<StudentDetails> list = new ArrayList<>();
     RecyclerView recyclerView;
     TargetDataAdapter adapter;
```

...

```
adapter = new TargetDataAdapter(list);
```

Comment: i get this error "error: incompatible types: List<StudentDetails> cannot be converted to ArrayList<AndroidTargets>
" when i try your solution

Answer (score 0):

First you created a custom adapter and did not use it.
secondly you're trying to reduce the work load of the adapter by abstracting some of it functionality like onClickListeners, yet you still perform the onClick inside the adapter which almost defeat the purpose of the abstraction.
Finally, interfaces are basically to be implemented and I'm curious on how you missed that.

Below is a commented and correct snippet of your code, you will understand it better if and only if you read the comments.

> **First your adapter:**

```
public class TargetDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TargetDataAdapter.TargetViewHolder>{

    ArrayList<AndroidTargets> targetsArrayList;
    private Context context;
    private HandleClick mHandleClick;


    public TargetDataAdapter(ArrayList<AndroidTargets> mTargetData) {
        targetsArrayList = mTargetData;
    }

    public void setmHandleClick(HandleClick handleClick) {
        this.mHandleClick = handleClick;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TargetViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        context = viewGroup.getContext();
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.target_row,viewGroup,false);
        return new TargetViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TargetViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.androidTargetName.setText(targetsArrayList.get(i).FIELD1 );
        viewHolder.androidTargetNumber.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "API Level: %d", targetsArrayList.get(i).FIELD2));
        viewHolder.androidTargetShortName.setText(targetsArrayList.get(i).FIELD3);
        viewHolder.myClickableView.setClickable(true);

        viewHolder.myClickableView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Do your stuff
                mHandleClick.onItemClick(i);//here is where you call the onItemClick method in the interface
            }
        });

    }

    public interface HandleClick {

        void onItemClick(int index);

    }
}
```

> **Your ShowStudentDetailsActivity:**

```
    //Take note of the implements keyword
        public class ShowStudentDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity, implements HandleClick {


            DatabaseReference databaseReference;

            ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            ArrayList<StudentDetails> list = new ArrayList<>();

            RecyclerView recyclerView;

            TargetDataAdapter adapter;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_student_details);

                recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

                recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ShowStudentDetailsActivity.this));

                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ShowStudentDetailsActivity.this);

                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Data from Firebase Database");

                progressDialog.show();

                databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Police").child("Chats");

                databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                            StudentDetails studentDetails = dataSnapshot.getValue(StudentDetails.class);

                            list.add(studentDetails);
                        }

                        adapter = new TargetDataAdapter(list);

        /*The this keyword below parses whatever setmHandleClick() method needs that's present in that same class, which is the onItemClick() method in the interface that we implemented. So, the this keyword simply is a reference to ShowStudentDetailsActivity as an object, including all it resources like context */
                        adapter.setmHandleClick(this)

                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });
            }

    /* This is the result of the implemented interface above using implements keyword
       you will note that without the below method, our class will show error and it's
basically telling us to do like below. So, when you implement an interface, you will be forced to have all its method implemented like below also.
I will suggest you read more on interface in java.*/
        @Override
        void onItemClick(int index){
        //note that we have moved the code that was in the adapter back to the activity it self.
           Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
                 int myData = index;
                 intent.putExtra("myDataKey", myData);
                 startActivity(intent);
        }     
}
```

> **That's it.**

*Bonus, below is a little bit more better approach and readable version.*

> **Firstly I will put my interface in a separate file.**

```
public interface HandleClick {
    void onItemClick(int index);
}
```

> **Secondly my adapter:**

```
    public class TargetDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TargetDataAdapter.TargetViewHolder>{

        private ArrayList<AndroidTargets> targetsArrayList;
        private HandleClick mHandleClick;

/*Note that the constructor now take two params which helps us get ride of setmHandleClick() method.*/
        public TargetDataAdapter(ArrayList<AndroidTargets> mTargetData, HandleClick handleClick) {
            targetsArrayList = mTargetData;
            mHandleClick = handleClick;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public TargetViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View v= LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.target_row,viewGroup,false);
            return new TargetViewHolder(v);
        }

/* There is an interesting way to make below code neater by abstracting it back to the Activity incharge, let me know if you want that...priority now is to focus on fixing your issue. */
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TargetViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
            viewHolder.androidTargetName.setText(targetsArrayList.get(i).FIELD1 );
            viewHolder.androidTargetNumber.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "API Level: %d", targetsArrayList.get(i).FIELD2));
            viewHolder.androidTargetShortName.setText(targetsArrayList.get(i).FIELD3);
            viewHolder.myClickableView.setClickable(true);

            viewHolder.myClickableView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mHandleClick.onItemClick(i);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

> **My ShowStudentDetailsActivity:**

```
//Note that you can implement more than one interfaces, that's one of it's beauty.
public class ShowStudentDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity, implements HandleClick {
            private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

            ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            private ArrayList<StudentDetails> list = new ArrayList<>();

            private RecyclerView recyclerView;
            private TargetDataAdapter adapter;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_student_details);

                initRecyclerView();
                initProgressDialog("Loading Data from Firebase Database");

                progressDialog.show();

                databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Police").child("Chats");

                databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                            StudentDetails studentDetails = dataSnapshot.getValue(StudentDetails.class);

                            list.add(studentDetails);
                        }

                        adapter = new TargetDataAdapter(list, this);        
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });
            }

private void initProgressDialog(String msg){
   progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
   progressDialog.setMessage(msg);
}

private void initRecyclerView(){
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

/*LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL is to set the orientation of my list items in the recyclerView, and the boolean value When set to true, layouts from end to start, otherwise start to end.*/
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
}

@Override
void onItemClick(int index){
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
         int myData = index;
         intent.putExtra("myDataKey", myData);
         startActivity(intent);
     }        
}
```

Comment: thank you very much @Whales_Corps. i tried it but i get this error "error: incompatible types: ArrayList<StudentDetails> cannot be converted to ArrayList<AndroidTargets>" at the adapter = new TargetDataAdpater(list, this);

Comment: Yes, I did not actually notice that! and Yes you can't cast an ArrayList of Type StudentDetails into another ArrayList of type AndroidTargets.
So, I believe you should be able to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with you interface with you even you are not using in MainActivity.
Ex how to implement interface.

Step : 1  create interface in adapter :

```
 public interface IHomeSelector{
    void onCategorySelected(int postion);
}
```

Step : 2 In ViewHolder use interface

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

```
    private TextView category;
    private ImageView category_icon;
    private IHomeSelector iHomeSelector;


    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, IHomeSelector iHomeSelector) {
        super(itemView);
        category = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_title);
        category_icon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_icon);
        this.iHomeSelector = iHomeSelector;

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        iHomeSelector.onCategorySelected(getAdapterPosition());
    }
}
```

Step :3 Pass interface in adapter constructor

```
      public class HomeRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<String> mCategories = new ArrayList<>();
private Context mContext;
private IHomeSelector mIHomeSelector;

public HomeRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<String> mCategories, Context mContext, IHomeSelector mIHomeSelector) {
    this.mCategories = mCategories;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mIHomeSelector = mIHomeSelector;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.layout_category_list_item, null);
    return new ViewHolder(view, mIHomeSelector);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    ((ViewHolder)viewHolder).category.setText(mCategories.get(i));


    RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions()
            .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);

    Drawable iconResource = null;
    switch(mCategories.get(i)){
        case "Music":{
            iconResource = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_audiotrack_white_24dp);
            break;
        }

        case "Podcasts":{
            iconResource = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_mic_white_24dp);
            break;
        }
    }


    Glide.with(mContext)
            .setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
            .load(iconResource)
            .into(((ViewHolder)viewHolder).category_icon);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mCategories.size();
}
```

Last step implement interface in activity :

```
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements HomeRecyclerAdapter.IHomeSelector
```

{

```
private static final String TAG = "HomeFragment";


// UI Components
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

// Vars
private HomeRecyclerAdapter mAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> mCategories = new ArrayList<>();
private IMainActivity mIMainActivity;

public static HomeFragment newInstance(){
    return new HomeFragment();
}

@Override
public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
    if(!hidden){
        mIMainActivity.setActionBarTitle(getString(R.string.categories));
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    initRecyclerView(view);
    mIMainActivity.setActionBarTitle(getString(R.string.categories));
}


private void initRecyclerView(View view){
    mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mAdapter = new HomeRecyclerAdapter(mCategories, getActivity(),  this); // passing 3 rd parameter this for interface
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}



@Override
public void onCategorySelected(int postion) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCategorySelected: list item is clicked!");
        //Here implement you code not in adapter

}


   }
```

Just follow this step if still stuck let me know.Happy Coding!!!

Comment: forgive me. now am totally confused. m just a newbie. could you please use my code to explain. maybe then i will understand. thank you in advance.